# Symfony2 & MongoDB : FormType of a document with references

Tags: php, forms, mongodb, symfony

I have a problem with one of my forms. I have a "Resource" document linked to 3 other documents :

- Tags (ReferenceMany)
- Category (ReferenceOne)
- Data Repository (ReferenceOne)

Here is the definition of my document :

```
class Resource {

/**
 * @MongoDB\Id
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @MongoDB\String
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @MongoDB\String
 */
private $description;

/**
 * @MongoDB\ReferenceMany(targetDocument="Tag")
 */
protected $tags;

/**
 * @MongoDB\ReferenceOne(targetDocument="Category")
 */
private $category;

/**
 * @MongoDB\ReferenceOne(targetDocument="DataRepository")
 */
private $dataRepository;

/**
 * @MongoDB\file
 */
private $logo;

/**
 * @MongoDB\Boolean
 */
private $available;
```

And here is the formType for my "Resource" document :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('name');
    $builder->add('description');
    $builder->add('logo', 'file');
    $builder->add('available', 'checkbox');
    $builder->add('category', 'document', array(
        'class' => 'AppBundle:Category'
    ));
    $builder->add('tags', 'document', array(
        'class' => 'AppBundle:Tag',
        'multiple' => 'true'
    ));
    $builder->add('dataRepository', "document", array(
        'class' => 'PortailCatalogBundle:DataRepository'
    ));
}
```

The generated form is perfect but when I submit it, it doesn't seem to hydrate my entity as excepted. Here is the request :

```
["request"]=>
object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag)#7 (1) {
    ["parameters":protected]=>
    array(1) {
      ["resource"]=>
      array(7) {
        ["name"]=>
        string(14) "Ressource N°1"
        ["description"]=>
        string(28) "Juste un test parmi d'autres"
        ["available"]=>
        string(1) "1"
        ["category"]=>
        string(24) "551c02b5a246cb287c09bcde"
        ["tags"]=>
        array(2) {
          [0]=>
          string(24) "551c02b5a246cb287c09bcdc"
          [1]=>
          string(24) "551d0ac2a246cbe40809bc97"
        }
        ["dataRepository"]=>
        string(24) "551d650aa246cb700e09bc9d"
        ["_token"]=>
        string(40) "4adfcc295b2305c784347311d3bbad55c260c6ed"
      }
    }
  }
```

All those objectIds are the right ones but when submitted, the form generates errors for those 3 documents with the error "**This value is not valid.**"

I found the queries done right after the form submission :

```
db.category.find({ "_id": ObjectId("551e66a2a246cba51909bc9c") });
db.tag.find({ "_id": ObjectId("551e66a2a246cba51909bc9d") });
db.dataRepository.find({ "_id": ObjectId("551e66a2a246cba51909bc9e") });
```

As you can see, the objectIds don't match. I feel like i messed up the formType definition part.

I didn't find any documentation for this kind of form in the DoctrineMongoDBBundle ...
Any idea or documentation link ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There wasn't anything wrong in my source code. I did a composer update of the **doctrine/doctrine-odm** bundle and the form worked as intended (apparently a commit of the bundle was added).